# How to Move Window Opened Offscreen in Windows 11

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-11

I know this is a dupe in general, but the ones I found dealt with Windows 10 or older, and all had the same suggestions, none of which worked.

I have three monitors connected via Displayport to my video card. I also have an HDMI cable connected to the video card that I run to an extractor solely for audio. Windows 11 detects that HDMI/Extractor as a generic monitor in the Display Settings. Randomly Windows will open a window and/or app on that generic monitor. Most of the time I can do CTRL + Space + R, CTRL + Space + M, or Rt Click the app in the taskbar and select Move. However, I do find some apps that I am unable to get to work. I end up having to disconnect a bunch of stuff, reboot and in general spend 30-60min playing around until I get it to open somewhere I can work with.

Comment: Can you give an example of apps this happens with? Do they consistently do this?

Answer (score 0):

If the window is in focus you could probably use `win + shift + left/right arrow>`. I think this works on Windows 10. I know it works on my Windows 11 system.

If that doesn't work:

Open `system > display` and check if moving the "display" that corresponds to the HDMI cable to the other side helps. If this works, this may mean that the program was coded to open at specific coordinates.

If that doesn't help you can always:

1. Close the program
2. Disconnect the HDMI cable
3. Open the program and reconnect your HDMI

This should always work because Windows only directs windows to displays it detects

Comment: I know disconnecting the cable works, I'm trying to avoid that because it's a pita to get to, and half the time it happens it's when I'm trying to jump on a call and Teams opens up offscreen and I don't really have 20min to mess with it